# DB connection issue between H2 database 1.3.156 (or prior) and 1.3.157 (and onwards)

Tags: h2

As a part of recent migration to latest H2 database jar in my project, I came across a connection issue.

The way it works in our project is that one program starts H2 database in server mode and connects to the database. Another program in the same JVM uses the URL *"jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/myfolder/mydb;IGNORECASE=TRUE"* and tries creating a connection using java.sql.DriverManager to same database i.e. *Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(this.url, this.user, this.password);*

But the connection object is not getting created after I migrate to latest H2 jar (Earlier we were using 1.2.147 and it was working fine there). After some analysis, I could narrow down on the fact that if I use H2 version 1.3.156 or below, this code works fine but if I start using H2 version 1.3.157 or above, the connection is not created for the second program. I checked the changelog for both these versions (http://www.softpedia.com/progChangelog/H2-Database-Engine-Changelog-30870.html) but I could not find anything that might throw some light on this. Note that our H2 database does not contain any table with BLOB/CLOB column.

What could be the reason for the same?

Regards,
Aditya

**P.S.: Exception stacktrace:**

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Connection is broken: "java.net.ConnectException:
Connection refused: connect: localhost" [90067-174]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:332)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:161)
        at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectServer(SessionRemote.java:417)
        at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.jav
a:305)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:105)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:90)
        at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:73)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at com.avaya.induna.server.db.DBConnectionManagerImpl.getConnection(DBCo
nnectionManagerImpl.java:34)
        at com.avaya.induna.server.db.backup.BackupImplThread.takeBackup(BackupI
mplThread.java:313)
        at com.avaya.induna.server.db.backup.BackupImplThread.run(BackupImplThre
ad.java:175)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at org.h2.util.NetUtils.createSocket(NetUtils.java:119)
        at org.h2.util.NetUtils.createSocket(NetUtils.java:100)
        at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.initTransfer(SessionRemote.java:100)
        at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectServer(SessionRemote.java:413)
        ... 9 more
```

Comment: Does it throw an exception? If yes, please post the exception message and stack trace. Or does the method not return? If yes, could you post a full thread dump?

Comment: added stacktrace FYR. I used H2 jar 1.3.173 here, but I get the same exception for any jar with version 1.3.157 or above.

Comment: I think either the server is not running, there is a firewall that blocks access to this port or IP address, or your TCP/IP configuration (`/etc/hosts`) is problematic.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of your options are valid. I start my web server (Tomcat) while having H2 1.3.156 jar in its classpath. I try running my program and it runs fine. Then I stop Tomcat, replace H2 1.3.156 with H2 1.3.157 jar and start Tomcat again (in both cases, H2 jar is renamed to 'h2.jar' as that is its name in the classpath). My program does not run now and I get the error mentioned above.

Comment: Could you check if you can connect to the server using telnet, port 9092?

Comment: No, telnet to 9092 also does not work if I use H2 jar 1.3.157 or above and run my application. It works with H2 jar 1.3.156 or below (as expected).

Comment: OK so it looks like the server didn't start at all with the newer version of H2. How do you start the server? Is there any exception in the log files?

Comment: You are right Thomas, the server indeed has not started.</br>The code to start server is:  Server s = Server.createTcpServer( new String[] {tcpflag} );  The value of 'tcpFlag' is empty string by default (or can be '-tcpAllowOthers' based on some condition if true).  This statement however is giving an exception saying 'feature not supported' if I use H2 1.3.157 or above jar.

Comment: So what should be the correct way to call the method if I do not want to specify '-tcpAllowOthers' flag?

Comment: I would probably use make it a boolean (`boolean allowOthers = ...`) and then use `Server.createTcpServer( allowOthers ? new String[] {"-tcpAllowOthers"} : new String[]{} );`. It is a little bit verbose thought.

Comment: I just used Server.createTcpServer() and it worked fine (atleast the program ran successfully). I hope it is ok to call this method without any parameters.

Comment: Sure! I will add an answer below, in case somebody else also runs into this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that there was a change in H2 version 1.3.157 (and onwards) in that parameters for starting the H2 TCP server are checked more strictly now. This caused the server not to start. For example, in H2 version 1.3.156 and older, the following was allowed:

```
Server.createTcpServer("");
```

while in later versions this fails.